# Unable to referance a bool across scripts Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, boolean

I am making a scipt in where once the bool "sniped" is triggered by the hunter an object is spawned in the spawner script. I referenced the hunter script in the unity inspector but I am still coming up with errors.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using UnityEngine;

public class Hunter : MonoBehaviour
{
    private GameObject enemy;
    public float speed = 10f;
    public bool sniped = false;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        enemy = GameObject.FindWithTag("duck");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    { 
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, enemy.transform.position, (speed *Time.deltaTime));

    }
    public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        
        Debug.Log("hit");
        Destroy(gameObject);
        Destroy(enemy);
        sniped = true;
    }

}
```

This is the Hunter script and this is the spawner one

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Spawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Hunter script;
    public GameObject enemy;
    public GameObject hunter;
    public GameObject piece;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
   

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Hunter.sniped == true)
        {

        }

    }
}
```

it is bare bones as the line "if (Hunter.sniped == true)" keeps giving errors and is unable to actually referance the bool. I am pretty new to unity and would appreciate any help I can get.

I tried referencing the script through the GetComponent command but that did not work I keep getting the error that the bool referanced is required for a non static field but I do not know how to fix this.

Comment: you can use static variables. [Unity Lecture on Static Variables](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I57PPyA_Dgg&pp=ygUWdW5pdHkgc3RhdGljIHZhcmlhYmxlcw%3D%3D)

Comment: @Obscure021 of course you *can* use `static` fields .. but you can not use a non-staic field like if it was one ;)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're trying to refer to a hunter in your game, but by saying `Hunter` you are actually talking about the *class* hunter, not any specific hunter. For that you would need a referance to a specific hunter instance.

But it looks like you already have that!

This line here

```
public Hunter script;
```

Is a refereance to a hunter, but you have called that reference `script`

So when you want to use the reference later, you need to use this name, not the name of the class.

Like this:

```
void Update()
{
    if (script.sniped == true)
    {

    }
}
```

I'd maybe reccomend re-naming this to something a little more obvious, such as

```
public Hunter hunterInstance;

void Update()
{
    if (hunterInstance.sniped == true)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Ok wow that fixed it, thank you for making this so simple I appreciate it since I am just starting out.

Answer (score 0):

You have created an object script for the class Hunter. To access variable and methods inside the hunter class you need to use the object name and not the class name.
Hunter.sniped should be script.sniped

This video on accessing variables from another script should help you with the basics.
https://youtu.be/Xtb-uaZROYQ